# Find & replace in files within a folder using Google Apps Script

Tags: replace, google-apps-script, find, directory, google-docs

Could you post a Snippet that does find & replace across all files within a folder please?

I did find something similar, 
[Google Scripts - Find and Replace Function that searches multiple documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755956/google-scripts-find-and-replace-function-that-searches-multiple-documents)

but that one search in **every** file in Google Drive, not within a folder. Since I'm only learning Google Apps Script by example now, I can't make that tiny step myself.

**EDIT: Further on the replacing part.**

The `DocumentApp.openById` returns a type of `Document` right?

However, I can't find the `replaceText` method in the `Document` type doc:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document

Fine, I then dig deeper, and found another example, 
[Google Apps Script document not accessible by replaceText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311223/google-apps-script-document-not-accessible-by-replacetext), which indicates that the `replaceText` method should be invoked from `var body = doc.getActiveSection()`. However, I can't find the `getActiveSection` method in [the `Document` type doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document) either.

Please help. thx

Comment: `var doc = DocumentApp.openById('doc id');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.findText('searchPattern')`  instead of body you can work with headers and footers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to get a hold of your folder, this can be done in a few ways.

If you are writing a script for a limited audience, and you are working with only a particular folder you can use DriveApp.getFolderById(id).  The id can be found in the url of your drive web app when you navigate to a folder as such:

```
https://drive.google.com/a/yourcompany.com/?tab=mo#folders/0B5eEwPQVn6GOaUt6Vm1GVjZmSTQ
```

Once you have that id, you can simply using the same code in the answer you reference, iterate through the file iterator for that particular folder as such:

```
function myFunction() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B5eEwPQVn6GOaUt6Vm1GVjZmSTQ").getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
   doc.replaceText("My search string or regex", "My replacement string");
 }
 Logger.log("Done")
}
```

Alternative way of getting the folder if you only know its name are the use of DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name) which returns a folder iterator.  If you know you have only one folder of that name, then you need to simply get the first and only element in the iterator as such:

```
function myFunction() {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("myfoldername");
  var myFolder = null;
  if (folders.hasNext())
    myFolder = folders.next();
  if (myFolder !== null) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // exit gracefully
  }
```

Further if you have multiple folders with the same name, you would have to iterate through them in a while loop (similar to the file iterator in the code you linked) and find a marker that proves this is the folder you are looking for (i.e. you could have an empty file with a particular name in there)

Comment: I have further question on the replacing part, and have updated the OP. Please help. thx.

Comment: Can I ask why you accepted the answer if the provided code doesn't work?  Seems strange to me ...

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see your answer previously. As said before, I'm only learning Google Apps Script by example now, I can't make tiny steps myself. I accepted the answer for the folder iterate code, assuming that the code that I found was correct. Moving past this tiny step, and I bumped into new problem.