# Script not changing data on template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I have been trying to create a script that will email me a report when a form is completed. It is currently sending the email and PDF properly, but it is not replacing the Key data with data from the form. What am I doing wrong?

#### Code.gs

```js
var docTemplate = "19vFf3Mzo9GbD2xyWmRHlbFMnVZuXC4TdF44bCQR9SfY";
var docName = "Test Form2PDF";

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var email_address = "email@goeshere.net";
  var Field1 = e.values[1];
  var Field2 = e.values[2];
  var Field3 = e.values[3];
  var Field4 = e.values[4];
  var Field5 = e.values[5];
  var Field6 = e.values[6];
  var Field7 = e.values[7];

  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id                        
  var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
    .makeCopy(docName + ' for ' + Field1)
    .getId();

  // Open the temporary document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

  // Get the document’s body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
  copyBody.replaceText('keyField1', Field1);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyField2', Field2);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyField3', Field3);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyField4', Field4);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyField5', Field5);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyField6', Field6);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyField7', Field7);
  // Save and close the temporary document
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  // Convert temporary document to PDF
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

  // Attach PDF and send the email
  var subject = "Test Form Report";
  var body = "Here is the test form for " + Field1 + "";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: pdf
  });

  // Delete temp file
  DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

#### docTemplate

```
Process: Responsible IT Resource to fill out form and send to
appropriate stakeholder for approval prior to making ANY change
to the Network/Server environment.

1. DESCRIPTION: keyField1

2. SYSTEMS IMPACTED: KeyField2

3. START DATE/TIME/DURATION: KeyField3

4. BENEFITS: KeyField4

5. RESPONSIBLE IT RESOURCES/CONTACT INFO: KeyField5

6. BUSINESS IMPACT: [How will this affect the business?]: KeyField6

7. TESTING: [what is the test plan]: KeyField7
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that the `keyField`s in your template document have different capitalization than in your code - therefore they are not found for the `replaceText()` method.

The advice in [Google Apps Script document not accessible by replaceText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311223/google-apps-script-document-not-accessible-by-replacetext/16311498#16311498) applies here as well; your keys would be better if they included odd punctuation. And they'd be less error-prone (and more obvious) if they were in all caps, e.g. `%KEYFIELD1%`. And even better with meaningful names, e.g. `%DESCRIPTION%`, `%SYSTEMS_IMPACTED%`, etc.